# Error with unicode-math and pgfplotstable

Tags: luatex, pgfplotstable, unicode-math

I was trying to make a table with `pgfplotstable` and append one csv file to another by `\pgfpotstablevertcat`. Now I wanted to change the math font with `unicode-math`, but then I get the error "File ended while scanning use of `\pgfplotslistpushback`".
I am using `lualatex` from MiKTeX to compile the document. Same problem for `xelatex`. 
What could be the issue? Is it a bug or am I missing something obvious?
Here is a MWE which produces the error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{dataA.csv}
pH,     concentration
1,      1.5
2,      -0.5
3,      -1.5
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{dataB.csv}
pH,     concentration
4,      -2.5
5,      -3.5
6,      -4.5
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableset{col sep=comma}
\pgfplotstablevertcat{\outputa}{dataA.csv} % loads `dataA.csv' -> `\outputa'
\pgfplotstablevertcat{\outputa}{dataB.csv} % appends rows of dataB.csv
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={pH, concentration},fixed zerofill]{\outputa};
\end{document}
```

Comment: I know it uses `\output` in the manual but don't use `\output` here!!!! if you redefine `\output` latex will not be able to output any pages.

Comment: I raised this at https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/375

Comment: Raised also at https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/149/

Comment: Ok, I changed `\output` to `\outputa`

Comment: See https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/code/ci/52a5e82389a28596a9673e4a9a2c8c9e7236001c/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\to` gets defined which breaks the pgf loop construct used here. You can locally make it safe again.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}




\begin{filecontents}{dataA.csv}
pH,     concentration
1,      1.5
2,      -0.5
3,      -1.5
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{dataB.csv}
pH,     concentration
4,      -2.5
5,      -3.5
6,      -4.5
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
$a$

\tracingmacros1
{\let\to\relax
\pgfplotstableset{col sep=comma}
\pgfplotstablevertcat{\outputa}{dataA.csv} % loads `dataA.csv' -> `\output'
\pgfplotstablevertcat{\outputa}{dataB.csv} % appends rows of dataB.csv
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={pH, concentration},fixed zerofill]{\outputa};
}
\end{document}
```

Or a global but safe definition such as

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}

\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{unicode-math}
\protected\def\to{\rightarrow}


\usepackage{pgfplotstable}




\begin{filecontents}{dataA.csv}
pH,     concentration
1,      1.5
2,      -0.5
3,      -1.5
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{dataB.csv}
pH,     concentration
4,      -2.5
5,      -3.5
6,      -4.5
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
$a$


\pgfplotstableset{col sep=comma}
\pgfplotstablevertcat{\outputa}{dataA.csv} % loads `dataA.csv' -> `\output'
\pgfplotstablevertcat{\outputa}{dataB.csv} % appends rows of dataB.csv
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={pH, concentration},fixed zerofill]{\outputa};

\end{document}
```

Comment: The error is in `pgfplots` which shouldn't use `\to` as argument delimiter for macros passed through `\edef`, but an internal nonexpandable control sequence. Anyway, `\AtBeginDocument{\let\to\rightarrow}` fixes the issue more easily.

Comment: Filed ticket: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/149/

Comment: Works perfect for me! Is there an advantage/disadvantage of one option? Or are they really equivalent?

Comment: @Schewerle the second is better as (in theory) you might want to use some math expression involving `\to` within the typesetting of the table, but in the first form it is locally made `\relax` (which does nothing) but in the second form it is still a right arrow.